# How to use input into an @completion function

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

How would I go about inputing a string into a completion function like     `func getCoordinates(completion: @escaping ((Double, Double, String) -> Void)) {` where `(Double, Double, String)` is the output. Sorry, I'm new to Swift so forgive me if I'm missing something.

Clarification, my current code looks something like this:

```
func getCoordinates(completion: @escaping ((Double, Double, String) -> Void)) {
    completion(lat!, long!, name!)
}
```

It's not that I can't return variables with a completion, it's that I don't know I would input a variable into getCoordinates.

Comment: Did you mean `getCoordinates() { value1, value2, string in  //do something with input variables }`

Comment: Update: I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65999965/how-to-pass-arguments-into-a-function-with-completion-swift

Answer (score 0):

Given following are your outputs.

```
let double1: Double = 1.2
let double2: Double = 2.3
let string: String = "Test"
```

You would call completion like this.

```
completion(double1, double2, string)
```

Comment: Sorry should've clarified, it's not the output that's the problem but the input. I've had no problem calling completion but rather inputting variables into the function.